# select rows by datetime in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to select rows which are inbetween a startdate and an enddate in c# with sqlite.

my dates are formatted like this:

```
2015-05-16T17:22:04.920+02:00
```

which should be a valid format for sqlite (ref: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

i am trying to select the row like this:

```
string CmdString = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename +  "WHERE DATETIME(timekey) >= DATETIME('2015-05-16T17:22:04.920+02:00') AND DATETIME(timekey) <= DATETIME('2015-05-16T17:24:04.920+02:00')";
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(CmdString, con);
SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable MatchDt = new DataTable();

sda.Fill(MatchDt);
```

The Error i get is:

```
SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing a space before the WHERE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space char before the where:

```
string CmdString = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename +  " WHERE DATETIME(timekey) >= DATETIME('2015-05-16T17:22:04.920+02:00') AND DATETIME(timekey) <= DATETIME('2015-05-16T17:24:04.920+02:00')";
```

And I would reccomend using the `BETWEEN` operator:

```
string CmdString = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename +  " WHERE DATETIME(timekey) BETWEEN DATETIME('2015-05-16T17:22:04.920+02:00') AND DATETIME('2015-05-16T17:24:04.920+02:00')";
```